# unable to create a file in new directory in java

Tags: java-io

I am trying to create a file in a new directory for which I had written a code in Java such that firstly a directory is made after that a file is created in that directory but while executing the code I found that the directory is created but the file is not and it is giving the error that `The system cannot find the path specified`.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ankit\workspace\SP_CentralSubPub\src\Publishers\0\qw.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.doing.mains.receiveFile(mains.java:65)
    at com.example.doing.mains.PublisherIdlFile(mains.java:41)
    at com.example.doing.mains.main(mains.java:21)
```

Comment: You can indent code blocks or copied in content with four spaces so it doesn't get mangled by rewrapping

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what's happening is, you might be creating a directory called "DirectoryName\filename.txt", then trying to create a new file called the same thing, this obviously isn't going to work.

So, instead of...

```
File file = new File("DirectoryName\\filename.txt");
file.mkdir();
file.createNewFile();
```

Try. .

```
 File file = new File("DirectoryName\\filename.txt");
 file.getParentFile().mkdir();
 file.createNewFile();
```

hope it helps.